# Hint Taylor Series $x^{2}\ln(x)$ about $a=1$

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

Find the taylor series of $g(x):= x^{2}\ln(x)$ about $a=1$

**Idea**: I would have thought we should find the Taylor series of $\ln(x)$ about $a=1$, which is

$\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k!}(x-1)^{k}$ and then I would just multiply that with $x^{2}$. So, we'd get:

$\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k!}(x-1)^{k}x^2$

This cannot be simplified can it? Surely there must be a better without having to calculate the $n$-th derivative of $x^2\ln(x)$

Comment: The product of two Taylor series is the Taylor series of the product. What you wrote is still not the Taylor series at $a=1$, since the taylor series of $x^2$ at $a=1$ is not $x^2$.

Comment: You might do better if you let $y=x-1$ and found the Taylor series of $h(y)=(1+y)^2 \log_e(1+y)$ about $b=0$

Comment: @Henry Does it always hold that we rewrite the taylor series about $b=0$ and then are we **ALWAYS**  allowed to use the "plugging in", for example the taylor polynomial of $e^{x^{2}+2x}$ is simply $\sum\frac{(x^2+2x)^n}{n!}$ about $0$

Comment: Not *always* - that will not work with the series at $x=\pm\infty$.  But otherwise, I suspect it should work: you want the expansion at $c$ to be in terms based on of $(x-c)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your answer  is  no completely correct. As you would like the expansion around $a=1$, you should also expand $x^2$ around this point. In fact, you can easily show that
$$x^2 = 1 +2 (x-1) + (x-1)^2\;.$$
As a result, we have that
$$x^2 \ln x = \Bigl[1 +2 (x-1) + (x-1)^2 \Bigr] \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}k (x-1)^k\;.$$

Or, after expanding
$$x^2 \ln x = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}k (x-1)^k + 2 \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}k (x-1)^{k+1} + \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}k (x-1)^{k+2}\\
= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}k (x-1)^k + 2 \sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k}}{k-1} (x-1)^{k} + \sum_{k=3}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k-2} (x-1)^{k}\\
= (x-1) + \frac32 (x-1)^2 +\sum_{k=3}^\infty  (-1)^{k+1}\left[\frac{1}{k} - \frac{2}{k-1} + \frac{1}{k-2} \right] (x-1)^k.$$